# Accessing value from outside for loop in xsl 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

Im creating an xml from another xml using xslt2.0. The source xml is something as below-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
    <set1>
        <line_data>
            <id>1</id>
            <some_data></some_data>
            <other_data></other_data>
            <allocation>
                <date>16-10-2023</date>
                <hours>1</hours>
            </allocation>
            <allocation>
                <date>23-10-2023</date>
                <hours>2</hours>
            </allocation>
            <allocation>
                <date>30-10-2023</date>
                <hours>3</hours>
            </allocation>
            <allocation>
                <date>06-11-2023</date>
                <hours>3</hours>
            </allocation>
        </line_data>
        <line_data>
           <id>2</id>
            <allocation>
                ....
            </allocation>
        </line_data>
        <line_data>
            
        </line_data>
    </set1>
    <entry>
        <id>1</id>
        <line_data>
            <week_hours>
                <start_date>23-10-2023</start_date>
                <time_hr>5</time_hr>
            </week_hours>
            <week_hours>
                <start_date>06-11-2023</start_date>
                <time_hr>10</time_hr>
            </week_hours>
        </line_data>
    </entry>
</Data>
```

I want to extract data from node  <line_data> where the  matches the  in  node.For each  tag, I need to check if there is a node with the same date in the /<week_hours>/<start_date>, then I need to replace the hours in allocation with hours from  where there is a match.
So the resulting xslt will look like -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
    <id>1</id>
    <some_data></some_data>
    <other_data></other_data>
    <allocation>
        <date>16-10-2023</date>
        <hours>1</hours>
    </allocation>
    <allocation>
        <date>23-10-2023</date>
        <hours>5</hours>
    </allocation>
    <allocation>
        <date>30-10-2023</date>
        <hours>3</hours>
    </allocation>
    <allocation>
        <date>06-11-2023</date>
        <hours>10</hours>
    </allocation>
</Data>
```

I have tried using -

```
 <xsl:variable name="vid" select="entry/id"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vExtendAppForecast" >
            <xsl:copy-of select="entry/line_data"/>
        </xsl:variable>
<xsl:for-each select=set1/line_data[id=$vid]/allocation>
<xsl:variable name="vStartDate" select="date"/>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="exists($vExtendAppForecast[week_hours/wd:start_date=$vStartDate]")
 -- replace hours with hours from variable
<xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
 <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
<xsl:otherwise>
</choose>
```

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you're making a completely unnecessary copy of a subtree. You can replace

```
<xsl:variable name="vExtendAppForecast" >
    <xsl:copy-of select="entry/line_data"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

with

```
<xsl:variable name="vExtendAppForecast" select="entry/line_data"/>
```

But that's not relevant to your problem.

The simplest approach is to use the idiom `(X, Y)[1]` which (provided X can only return at most one item) returns X if it exists, otherwise Y. This means you can replace your entire `xsl:choose` with:

```
<allocation>
  <xsl:copy-of select="$vStartDate"/>
  <hours>
     <xsl:value-of 
          select="($vExtendAppForecast[week_hours/wd:start_date=$vStartDate]/time_hr,
                  .)[1]"/>
  </hours>
</allocation>
```

I haven't tested that this produces exactly the right output, but hopefully it illustrates the idea.

The idiom `(X, Y)[1]` is sufficiently common that the proposals for XSLT 4.0 include an operator `X otherwise Y`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this method. However, it is not returning me the desired output. It is not finding any match for start date.

Comment: I gave a simplified xml as the source. The actual one is below -

Comment: The actual one is big and it is not allowing me to post it in comments.

Comment: It worked now. I just took week_hours outside of the where condition brackets -
```
<allocation>
  <xsl:copy-of select="$vStartDate"/>
  <hours>
     <xsl:value-of 
          select="($vExtendAppForecast/week_hours[wd:start_date=$vStartDate]/time_hr,
                  .)[1]"/>
  </hours>
</allocation>

Comment: I am not able to tag to you somehow. Thanks for the help!